# Combobox in JavaFX application does not dropdown

Tags: macos, javafx, fullscreen

I have some javafx code that I want to run in full screen mode. It contains a combobox. When I run the application in full screen mode, the dropdown popup does not appear when I click the drop box. How can I fix it.

Here is my code.

main file:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author movingstories
 */
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml")));


            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

form fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@common.css" />
        <URL value="@participantdetails.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="nextBtn" layoutX="822.0" layoutY="620.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next" />
      <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" layoutX="440.0" layoutY="314.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="442.0" layoutY="349.0" text="Email" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="482.0" layoutY="314.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label layoutX="443.0" layoutY="318.0" text="Name" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="genderField" layoutX="481.0" layoutY="376.0" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="ageField" layoutX="481.0" layoutY="408.0" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label layoutX="443.0" layoutY="412.0" text="Age" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField fx:id="emailField" layoutX="482.0" layoutY="345.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label layoutX="635.0" layoutY="412.0" text="yrs" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label layoutX="440.0" layoutY="380.0" text="Gender" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and the fxml controller

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author movingstories
 */
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox genderField;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

        genderField.getItems().add("Male");
        genderField.getItems().add("Female");
    }    

}
```

The main file contains the line `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);`. If I comment this line, I can see the combox box works.

Comment: That looks like a bug. I see the same effect (you don't need anything that complex to see it, just a `ComboBox` in a full screen window). What JDK version do you have and what platform are you running on?

Answer (score 3):

I tested on Mac OS X 10.9.5; I saw the same effect you describe under JDK 1.7.0_67, JDK 1.8.0_20, and JDK 1.8.0_25. It appears to be fixed in JDK 1.8.0_40 ea b07 ([early access](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)).

I used this simpler test case:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FullScreenComboBoxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

            ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Male", "Female"));
            combo.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasShowing, Boolean isShowing) {
                    System.out.println("Showing: "+isShowing);
                }
            });

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setTop(combo);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

This actually applies to any popup window (indeed, any secondary window at all) on Mac OS X in full screen mode. So context menus, tooltips etc will not work either. This is [RT-38338](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38338).

Comment: yeah, actually all the input controls behave weird. The cursor does not appear for text fields and all the nightlights for the focused fields are lost. I will test with update 40. Just out of curiosity, any idea what was the fix in update 40? Thanks!

Comment: As I understand it, prior to version 40, they rolled their own full screen implementation. This was because they wanted to support OS X versions prior to 10.7, which didn't have native full screen support. Since those versions of OS X aren't supported platforms in Java 1.8, they now use native full screen support. (Again, that's as I understand it; no guarantee I am correct.)